# how to call another http on each bottomnavigationbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, http-post

I want to make codes for my app by flutter.

Without bottomnavigationbar, my app works well.

But there are some problem.
I input bottomnavigationbar with _widgetOptions in my coding, it occured one problem.

1. The program coundn't display http result, which was displayed without _widgetOptions.

**This is my coding without _widgetOptions, it works well**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Post.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter ListView'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // late List<Post> posts;    //good
  late List<Post> posts = <Post>[];
  late bool loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    Services.getPosts().then((list) {
      setState(() {

        posts
          ..clear()
          ..addAll(list);

        // posts = list;    //good
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Posts'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        // crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Date',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Koreanwon/us\$',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Koreanwon',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('US \$',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Post post = posts[index];
                      return Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Row(
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.date))),
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.rate))),
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Center(child: Text(post.koreanwon))),
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.dollar))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        // ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**This coding with bottomnavigationbar, could not display post result**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Post.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter ListView'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<Post> posts = <Post>[];
  late bool loading;
  late List _widgetOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    Services.getPosts().then((list) {
      setState(() {
        posts
          ..clear()
          ..addAll(list);
        // posts..addAll(list);
        loading = false;
      });
    });
    _widgetOptions = [
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Date',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Koreanwon/us\$',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Koreanwon',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('US \$',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Post post = posts[index];
                      return Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Row(
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.date))),
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.rate))),
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Center(child: Text(post.koreanwon))),
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.dollar))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),


      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Date',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Koreanwon/us\$',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Koreanwon',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('US \$',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 2.5,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                            )))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Post post = posts[index];
                      return Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Row(
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.date))),
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.rate))),
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Center(child: Text(post.koreanwon))),
                              Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.dollar))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),


    ];
  }

  @override
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Posts'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        //현재 선택된 Index
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Favorites'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Music'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Places'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('News'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// }
```

Comment: Try to put your _widgetOptions inside the build method.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea how to do.